# Replace Docky's Icon by Ubuntu Icon

Tags: icons, dock, docky

How can I replace Docky's standard anchor icon in the dock by Ubuntu's? It would look quite nice I think. This is how it looks right now:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Normally, docky's icon is dynamically drawn by the program so that it is colored based on your GTK theme. So, the first thing we need to do is turn that off. Launch the "Run Application" dialog by pressing `Alt+F2`. Then run `gconf-editor` from that prompt.

Now browse to `/apps/docky-2/Docky/Items/DockyItem/` Select the `Hue` key and change the setting to `1`

[image]

Now that docky will use the theme icon directly, you can change the icon in the theme. The theme will be found in `/usr/share/icons` if it is installed system wide or `~/.icons/` if it is installed locally.

For Faenza, you'll want to replace `/usr/share/icons/Faenza/apps/scalable/dock.svg` with the icon you want. You'll probably want to use `/usr/share/icons/Faenza/places/scalable/distributor-logo-ubuntu.svg` Depending on the size of your dock, may also need to replace some of the other sizes as well.

[image]

You'll need to restart docky.

Comment: Thanks for this excellent reply! I have already marked it as answered, as most likely your proposal will work for most users.
However, I have the problem that the entry "DockyItem" does not exist on my computer. Therefore, my beautiful Ubuntu logo is now raped by Docky and colored blue.

Comment: This option wasn't added until a recent docky release. Try upgrading to the PPA version: https://launchpad.net/~docky-core/+archive/ppa

Comment: How would I change the icon if I didn't use the Faenza icon-theme? I couldn't figure out where to place the icon I want. My theme is the regular ubuntu-mono-light.

Comment: The default icon theme doesn't ship docky icons, so it falls back to the icons shipped with docky itself. You'll have to replace these ones. They can be found under `/usr/share/icons/hicolor/`

Comment: Took some work but I can confirm that this does the trick.